# How to GRANT priveleges to non-superuser to execute function pg_read_binary_file?

Tags: postgresql, security, privileges

In PostgreSQL I have a database with a custom function witch loads binary content of the file in database table by using the system function `pg_read_binary_file`.

If I ran this custom funtion under a user with superuser rights, it executes successfuly. But when the user does not have superuser rights, I receive an error:

```
permission denied for function pg_read_binary_file
```

I thought that all that I need is to simply `GRANT` permissions to `EXECUTE` the funtion for such user, so I did the following:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_read_binary_file(text,bigint,bigint,boolean) TO someuser;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_read_binary_file(text,bigint,bigint) TO someuser; 
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_read_binary_file(text) TO someuser;
```

If I check the permissions by

```
SELECT proacl FROM pg_proc WHERE proname='pg_read_binary_file';
```

I get:

```
{postgres=X/postgres,someuser=X/postgres}
{postgres=X/postgres,someuser=X/postgres}
{postgres=X/postgres,someuser=X/postgres}
```

As I understand, now `someuser` has permission to execute the function `pg_read_binary_file`. But when I try to run my custom function, I still receive the same error:

```
permission denied for function pg_read_binary_file
```

So the question is how to give permission to a non-superuser to execute the function `pg_read_binary_file`? Maybe there are some additional permissions that must be granted, but it is not obvious.

In the [documentation on Portgres system functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) for `pg_read_binary_file` it is written that:

> Restricted to superusers by default, but other users can be granted `EXECUTE` to run the function.

I searched for some additional information about the way how can I give such permissions, but without luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

1. You are using an old PostgreSQL version.

   Before [commit e79350fef2917522571add750e3e21af293b50fe](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=e79350fef2917522571add750e3e21af293b50fe), this was not governed by permissions on the functions, but by hard-coded checks in the function itself.

   This doesn't seem to be your case, however, because the error messages would then read:

   ```
   ERROR:  must be superuser to read files
   ```
2. You are not `someuser` when you try to execute the function. Test with

   ```
   SELECT current_user;
   ```
3. You are connected to a different database (e.g., you changed the permissions in the `postgres` database, but `someuser` connects to a different database).

Comment: Thanks for Your answer.


It was case 3. I granded permissions on database postgres, becouse I thought that system functions called from postgres database whenever database connects user, and also I sow pg_read_binary_file in object tree only in postgres database. After Your answer I granded permissions in working database and now all works fine.

So the answer - I must execute `GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_read_binary_file(text) TO someuser;` not on postgres database, but on working database.


Thank You again.